# jQuery HTML() loads invisible html content

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm trying to load html to the website div, but everytime it loads content, the div goes invisible, meaning, the html is loaded, the height is there but the content is invisible!

Any one can help?

(The code is divided (one in index.php other in costum.js))

```
<div class="chatMessages messages messages-img">


function load_messages(){        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../inc/class/chat/load.php",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.chatMessages').html(data);           
        }
    });
}
setInterval(load_messages,5000);
```

Comment: so should we guess your code? or you will post it?

Comment: Update @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: check your data with `console.log(data)` at start

Comment: Try doing a `console.log(data)` and show us the output/

Comment: Guys, I've checked the response of the POST, and the html is correctly received! The problem is once it is jQuery html() the content is inserted but is invisible!

Comment: http://beta.csgo.vision/ this is the website link! Check yourself whats happening!

Comment: the response of console.log(data) is the exactly html!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted the link to the site in a comment so I had a look. On line 3748 of theme-default.css you have the following:

```
.messages .item {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}
```

The opacity of each `.item` div is 0, hence being invisible. Removing the opacity property resolves the issue.

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much!

Comment: He likely rather wants to re-execute the transition

Comment: @Kryzek You should remove `filter: alpha(opacity = 0);` too.

Answer (score 1):

Since we dont have your code, i can only predict.

> 1. Your ajax is not returning any data.
> 2. Your 'said path' in ajax does not exist.
> 3. Ajax is returning some error.
> 4. You are hiding the content/div using CSS.
> 5. There is some other script, that is clearing the div.
> 6. Your text font is of same color as that of background. And many more possibilities.

I suggest you Inspect Element you page and check console for errors.

Comment: Hi sir! The ajax is returning the exact html that I need! The space of the html is there! But the thing is white :(

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle so that we can check it online.

Comment: @Kryzek You will need to give a valid path for your Ajax URL. Else i wont be able to verify the data.